# MySQL query: alternatives for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, information-schema

1. Why does INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES take ages to return result on my live server but not on my localhost? (I think it clashes my live server each time I perform this!)
2. Any alternatives for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to list all tables and numbers of record in each table?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'db_name'
```

What I need are only

```
<?php echo $item['TABLE_NAME'];?> (using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
<?php echo $item['TABLE_ROWS'];?> (using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

```
show table status
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Show Tables`. Although doubtful this will be much faster than an information_schema query. Unless your network connection is *dreadfully* slow
2. SELECT **TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS**
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'db_name'